# print to file in a loop 'R'

Tags: r, loops

I am a beginner to 'R'.  I have a loop where I shift data frames, merge them and then run a regression:

```
testsequence = seq(60,120000, by=60)
for(n in 1:length(testsequence)){
 dfshift<-tail(df, (nrow(df)-testsequence[n]))
 df1shift<-head(df1, (nrow(df1)-testsequence[n]))
 dftogether<-cbind(dfshift,df1shift)
 lm1<-lm(LPGT~Temp, data=dftogether)
 write.table(lm1, file = "OUTPUT_Sensitivity_Results.csv")
}
```

The last line triggers this error message:

```
"Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""lm"" to a data.frame"
```

Any ideas?  Also, I would like to structure it so that I don't overwrite my output file for each iteration of the loop.  I saw the thread that suggested the following:

```
means <- sapply(filename, function(x) mean(as.numeric(read.table(x,header=FALSE)$V4)))
```

And then write the file as a whole with:

`write.csv(data.frame(fname=filename,mean=means),file="output.csv")`

but I'm not sure how to apply it to my case.

Any help would be appreciated!

Sonja

Comment: `lm` doesn't return a data.frame, which would be needed as input for `write.table`. In fact, it is unclear what you'd like to write to file.

Comment: What exactly do you want to write to the file? `write.table` is for writting data.frames and matrices. You're trying to write an `lm` object. What exactly do you want that to look like in your output file? Are you trying to store a human-readable version? Do you just want to store the R object somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the lines that appear at the console as a result of the implicit Print in the REPL that runs at the top level of R, then use this instead:

```
 write( capture.output(print(lm1)),"\n",
        file="OUTPUT_Sensitivity_Results.txt",
        append=TRUE)
```

Note that I changed the file type so you would not think that it was a CSV file.